# how to round the output in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

For our webshop we get from the manufacturers a csv file (automatically updated) with product data.
Some manufacturers use prices without Tax and some within.

I want to change prices with a shell script to add 21% TAX and round it to nearest .95 or .50

**For example I get a sheet:**

```
sku|ean|name|type|price_excl_vat|price

EU-123|123123123123|Product name|simple|24.9900
```

**I use this code:**

```
sed -i "1 s/price/price_excl_vat/" inputfile
awk '{FS="|"; OFS="|"; if (NR<=1) {print $0 "|price"} else {print $0 "|" $5*1.21}}' inputfile > outputfile
```

**the output is:**

```
sku|ean|name|type|price_excl_vat|price

EU-123|123123123123|Product name|simple|24.9900|30.2379
```

**How do I round it to the correct price like below ?**

```
sku|ean|name|type|price_excl_vat|price

EU-123|123123123123|Product name|simple|24.9900|29.95
```

Comment: Why should `30.2379` not become `30.50` instead of `29.95` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 awk 'BEGIN      {FS=OFS="|"} 
      $NF==$NF+0 {a=$NF*1.21; 
                  r=a-int(a); 
                  if      (r<0.225) a=a-r-0.05; 
                  else if (r<0.725) a=a-r+0.50; 
                  else              a=a-r+0.95; 
                  $(NF+1)=a} 1'
```

note that in your example the nearest number for `30.2379` will be `30.50`  Perhaps you want to round down?

To round down instead of the nearest, and with a variable price column.  The new computed value will be appended to the end of the row.

```
 awk 'BEGIN    {FS=OFS="|"; k=5} 
      $k==$k+0 {a=$k*1.21; 
                r=a-int(a); 
                if      (r<0.50) a=a-r-0.05; 
                else if (r<0.95) a=a-r+0.50; 
                else             a=a-r+0.95; 
                $(NF+1)=a} 1'
```

Comment: awk was what I used. But with the normal print indeed round down to *.95 or *.50

Comment: did you try this script?  It will round to **NEAREST** 0.95 or 0.50.  You need to change the condition slightly to round **DOWN**, not to the nearest but better change the wording in your question to get the desired outcome.  Just to make clear, number ending with 0.94 will be rounded to 0.50 and number ending with 0.49 will be rounded to 0.95 (also cause a change in the integer digits)

Comment: Thanks ! I tried it, and it works fine with the example. But the working file has 40 columns. The price ex vat column is at the 5th and the price must be added after the last column, so in working file column 41. Then it isn't working, but I can't figure out why...

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '#define field separator in and out
     BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}

     # add/modify a 6th field for price label if missing on header only
     NR==1 && NF == 6 { $6 = "price"; print; next}
     NR==1 && NF == 5 { $6 = "price"; print; next}

     # add price with tva rounded to 0.01 if missing
     NF == 5 { $6 = int( $5 * 121 ) / 100 }

     # print the line (modified or not, ex empty lines) [7 is just a *not 0*)
     7
    ' inputfile \
 > outputfile
```

- self documented
- not sure about your sed for header becasue sample show already a header with price so take the one you want

Comment: You could use `printf`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what you're program looks like, it makes it difficult to give you more information.

However, both `awk` and `bash` have the [printf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/printf.3.html) command. This command can be used for rounding floating point numbers. (Yes, Bash is integer arithmetic, but it can pretend a number is a decimal number).

I gave you the link for the C `printf` command because the one for Bash doesn't include the formatting codes. Read it and weep because the documentation is a bit dense, and if you've never used `printf` before, it can be quite difficult to understand. Fortunately, an example will bring things to light:

```
$ foo="23.42532"
$ printf "%2.2f\n", $foo
$ 23.43   #All rounded for you!
```

The `f` means it's a *floating point* number. The `%` tells you that this is the beginning of a formatting sequence. The `2.2` means you want 2 digits on the left side of the decimal and two digits on the right. If you said `%4.2f`, it would make sure there's enough room for four digits on the left side of the decimal, and left pad the number with spaces. The `\n` on the end is the *New Line* character.

Fortunately, although `printf` can be hard to understand at first, it's pretty much the same in almost all programming languages. It's in `awk`, `Perl`, `Python`, `C`, `Java`, and many more languages. And, if the information you need isn't in `printf`, try the documentation on `sprintf` which is like `printf`, but prints the formatted text into a string.

The best documentation I've seen is in the [Perl `sprintf` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) because it gives you plenty of examples.